# LDAP authentication with Percona Server

Tags: mysql, authentication, percona

Reading over [this post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/08/14/getting-percona-pam-to-work-with-percona-server-its-client-apps/) it seemed to indicate this plugin allowed user authentication via LDAP

> Percona Server is bundled with the PAM plugin which opens a plethora
>   of ways to authenticate to MySQL such as restricting time when users
>   can connect to MySQL, authenticate via a USB key, authenticate to an
>   external authentication system such as **LDAP** and many, many more PAM
>   compatible mechanisms.

However that intro paragraph is the only mention of LDAP in the entire post.  I've read through that as well as the general [Percona PAM](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-pam-for-mysql/installation.html) installation post. Every setup instruction seems to be talking about authenticating against a local unix account.  No mention of specifying an LDAP server or anything.

I found one other [SourceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlauthldap/) and some other mentions of perhaps slapping mysql_proxy infront.  Frankly that SF project doesn't feel very production ready.

Am I missing something about this percona plugin being able to authenticate via LDAP?

If I'm completely off base with that plugin perhaps my larger questions is "How can I get users authenticated via LDAP?"

Comment: Technically, Percona's plugin is not an LDAP plugin, but for PAM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_modules It just happens that PAM is a very flexible authentication system (check http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/02/24/using-two-factor-authentication-with-percona-server/ ), allowing you to connect MySQL with LDAP. Follow http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/08/14/getting-percona-pam-to-work-with-percona-server-its-client-apps/ for a step by step setup for a Red Hat-based system.

Comment: As an addendum, a very typical problem we found when working with authentication plugins is that in most cases you need to work without hashing the password (it can be however SSL-encrypted). Make sure your client supports that http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cleartext-authentication-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Percona PAM Authentication Plugin for MySQL to successfully authenticate individual users via LDAP but so far I haven't managed to the group/proxy part working.

You do need to make sure that there is a PAM profile for MySQL, which is probably the bit that is missing (first question) from the article you linked. I had also read through that along the way.

I found this guide particularly helpful for getting it working (second question):

- http://www.arubin.org/blog/2012/07/16/mysql-pam-ldap-authentication-module-configuration/

I'm still in the process of finalising this all and once I'm finished I'll blog about my experience and update this post with more information. Hope this helped!

Comment: I'm sorry that I basically did this - https://xkcd.com/979